Properties of the Ideal of a Veronese variety
I have in mind the $d$-th Veronese embedding $\mathbb{P}^n \xrightarrow{\nu_d} \mathbb{P}^{\binom{d+n}{d}-1}$. But regardless, I would like to pose the following question:
Set
$$S:=\{(i_0,i_1,\ldots, i_n) \in \mathbb{N}^{n+1} \mid       i_0+\cdots+i_n=d\},$$
and consider the ideal
$$
\mathcal{I}=\langle z_I z_J-z_K z_L \mid I, J, K, L \in S \text{ and } I+J=K+L\rangle
$$
of $K[Z_I \mid I \in S]$.
In this post Image of the Veronese is defined by $X_I X_J=X_k X_L=0$, someone claims that the quadratic relations arising from $\mathcal{I}$ yield the more general fact:
$$
\sum_i I_i=\sum_i J_i \Longrightarrow  
 Z_{I_1} \cdots Z_{I_k}-Z_{J_1} \cdots Z_{J_k} \in \mathcal{I}.
$$
A proof by induction on $k\geq 2$ is suggested.
I've tried to this in many ways, and got nothing even for the case $k=3$.
Can someone please elaborate a bit on how to tackle this?

Hint: it suffices to increase the degree of $\gcd(Z_{I_k}, Z_{J_k})$ (except if $I_k = J_k$, in which case you reduce to the $k - 1$ case)

@ronno. $Z_{I_k}$ and $Z_{J_k}$ are independent variables, and then $\gcd\left(Z_{I_k}, Z_{J_k}\right)=1$. I'm not sure in what sense
I should increase this $\gcd$. Can you please elaborate it a bit more?

Right, sorry, bad abuse of notation. I mean $\sum_i \min((I_k)i, (J_k)i)$, which is the degree of the gcd of the image of $Z{I_k}$ and $Z{J_k}$ under the map of polynomial rings $Z_I \mapsto \prod_i X_i^{I_i}$.

And by "increase" I mean show that the relation $Z_{I_1} \dots Z_{I_k} = Z_{J_1} \dots Z_{J_k}$ is implied by another of the same form (along with the quadratic relations) but where this quantity is bigger.

@ronno.   I appreciate your clarification. While I'm still trying to fully grasp your suggestion, your comments have  triggered a new idea for me. Interestingly, it uses no induction at all.  Please, let me know your thoughts on it. Here it is:

Let's  consider the $K$-algebra homomorphism:
[
\begin{aligned}
\theta : K[Z_{I} \mid I \in S] & \longrightarrow K[x_0, \ldots, x_n] \
Z_I & \longmapsto x_0^{i_0}\cdots x_n^{i_n}
\end{aligned}
]
We may assume (as it holds true) that $\ker \theta = \mathcal{I}$. Now, observe the following:
[
\begin{aligned}
\theta( Z_{I_1} \cdots Z_{I_k}) &= \theta( Z_{I_1}) \cdots \theta(Z_{I_k}) \
&= x_0^{\sum\limits_{j=1}^k(I_j)0}\cdots x_n^{\sum\limits{j=1}^k(I_j)_n}
\end{aligned}
]
Given that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^k I_j = \sum\limits_{j=1}^k J_j$, it follows that:

[
\begin{aligned}
\theta( Z_{J_1} \cdots Z_{J_k}) &= x_0^{\sum\limits_{j=1}^k(I_j)0}\cdots x_n^{\sum\limits{j=1}^k(I_j)_n}
\end{aligned}
]
Consequently,
[
Z_{I_1} \cdots Z_{I_k} - Z_{J_1} \cdots Z_{J_k} \in \ker \theta = \mathcal{I}
]

I'm invoking something that may be far from trivial, namely $\ker \theta = \mathcal{I}$. So any simpler solution is welcome.

It seems circular to use that $\ker \theta = \mathcal{I}$ in proving that $\mathcal{I}$ cuts out the image of $\theta^*$

@ronno. Yes, you are right. But so far, I was not able to make any progress using the $\gcd$ approach.

Have you tried an example? Try inferring $(X^4 Y) (X^3Y^2)^2 = (X^5)^2 Y^5$ from the quadratic relations between $X^i Y^{5 - i}$.
